# How do I make a counter in Django that is displayed in the template?

Tags: python, django, templates, view, count

**Models.py**

```
class Coche(models.Model):  
    matricula = models.CharField(max_length=7,primary_key=True)
```

**Views.py**

```
class Index(ListView):
    model = Coche
    total_coches = Coche.objects.filter(reserved=False, sold=False)
```

**Template**

```
<span class="text-primary">{{ total_coches.count }}</span> <span>coches disponibles</span></span>
```

### It does not show the number of cars my application has. Does anyone know what the fault is? ###

Comment: The views.py file have template_name = index.html.

Comment: By the name of total_coches I'm guessing you want the count of coches in that line. so why not just getting the count in the same line inside your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass context to the template in Django generic views you need to use the get_context_data mixin.

```
class Index(ListView):
    model = Coche
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Index, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['total_coches'] = Coche.objects.filter(reserved=False, sold=False)
        return context
```

If you just need the counter instead of the whole queryset, it would be better to follow Kurosh's suggestion in the comments and define it in your view.

```
class Index(ListView):
    model = Coche
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Index, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['total_coches'] = Coche.objects.filter(reserved=False, sold=False).count()
        return context
```

Then in your template you just use `{{total_coches}}`.

Comment: Thanks you so much!